# Are the following conditionals equivalent

Tags: python, logic

Are the following conditionals equivalent?

```
      if (array[i][j] == 1 and (i,j) not in APP) or (array[i][j] == 1 and (i,j) in APP and IterateAPP == 1) :
            #do stuff
```

---

```
       if array[i][j] == 1:
            if (i,j) in APP:
                 if IterateAPP == 1:
                      #do stuff
                 elif IterateAPP == 0:
                      print "Doing nothing"
            if (i,j) not in APP:
                      #do stuff
```

Comment: Yes, apart from the `print "Doing nothing"` bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even simpler, you can factor out the common part:

```
if array[i][j] == 1 and (IterateAPP == 1 or (i,j) not in APP):
    # do stuff
```

Curious variable name conventions you've got there  :)

Answer (score 1):

If the code in `#do  stuff` is the same at both the places, then you can use the first snippet. But logic wise, they are the same...

And yeah, the first snippet does not cover the `print "Doing nothing"` part